# Django JSONField: None saved instead of empty strings

Tags: django, postgresql, data-cleaning

Working with Django, I have a JSONField in my database (PostgreSQL) where I store lists of dictionaries with actors' first names and last names. I want to form references to movies, with title, year, and actors' names. Actors'names can be left blank, and we should get a reference as "Titanic. 1997.", without any actors listed.

The problem is that I get the following error when I'm not inserting any actors' names into the forms:

> KeyError at /add-source/
>
> 'last_name'
>
> ...
>
> File "E:\Pycharm_projects\movieproject\movie_project\movies\views.py", line 40, in add_movie
>       'last_name': actor_form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
>   KeyError: 'last_name'

I have tried the following:

1) changing the JSONField parameters to null=True or blank=True, or both. To no avail;

2) changing **cleaned_data['last_name']** to **cleaned_data.get('last name')**. This eliminates the error, but actors are stored as None None in the JSONField and are inserted as gaps into the reference (instead of being ignored): "Titanic. 1997. Actors: ." instead of "Titanic. 1997.".

**The question is:** how can I avoid the error and what should I do to insert empty strings instead of None into the JSONField?

My code is the following:

**movie.py:**

```
class Movie(Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=400, blank=True)
    actors = JSONField(default=dict, blank=True)
    year = PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

In my **forms.py**:

```
class MovieForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ['title', 'year']

class ActorForm(Form):
    last_name = CharField(max_length=200, required=False)
    first_name = CharField(max_length=200, required=False)

ActorFormSet = formset_factory(ActorForm)
```

In **views.py**:

```
def add_movie(request):
    actor_formset = ActorFormSet(request.POST or None, prefix='actors')
    movie_form = MovieForm(request.POST or None)
    context = dict(actor_formset=actor_formset, movie_form=movie_form)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if movie_form.is_valid() and actor_formset.is_valid():
        movie = movie_form.save(commit=False)

        actors_list = []
        for actor_form in actor_formset:
            actor = {
                'last_name': actor_form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
                'first_name': actor_form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
            }
            actors_list.append(actor)

        movie.actors = actors_list
        movie.reference = movie.create_reference
        movie.save()
        return redirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        return render(request, 'movies/add-movie.html', context)
else:
    return render(request, 'movies/add-movie.html', context)
```

Comment: You can do `cleaned_data.get('last name', '')`. The second argument to `get` is default value returned when key is not found.

Comment: @Nafees Anwar That works for the database, I now have this list for actors: [{"last_name": "", "first_name": ""}]. But that still returns "Titanic. 1997. Actors: ." This is appended by a function which evaluates "if actors_list". So, it evaluates the list as existent, even though it has neither a last_name nor a first_name.

Comment: @NafeesAnwar  actors_list = [Actor(**kwargs) for kwargs in self.actors] if self.actors else [] – this method return an actors_list with a length of 1, even though both the last_name and the first_name are empty.

Comment: You can add a condition, `[Actor(**kwargs) for kwargs in self.actors if kwargs['first_name'] and kwargs['last_name']]`

Comment: @NafeesAnwar Works great. Would you add your comments as a separate answer, so that I would accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credits for the answer go to **Nafees Anwar** (unfortunately, he posted it only in the comments).

In order to avoid saving None, we need to check if at least one of the attributes exists for the Actor class. Then, we do a list comprehension by unpacking each Actor object if it has any such attribute. So, in views.py from the original question, we should replace this:

```
actors_list = []
    for actor_form in actor_formset:
        actor = {
            'last_name': actor_form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
            'first_name': actor_form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
        }
        actors_list.append(actor)
```

by this:

```
actors_list = [Actor(**kwargs) for kwargs in self.actors if kwargs['first_name'] or kwargs['last_name']]
```

If we need all of the attributes to be non-empty, we just check that all of the Author kwargs are present:

```
...if kwargs['first_name'] and kwargs['last_name']]   # use 'and' instead of 'or'
```